# How to add a button to matplotlib.pylab.imshow() dialog?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to do additional operations on the image displayed by matplotlib.pyplot.imshow() method.

For Example:
I want an extra button "Display ROI" where it displays the ROI of the co-ordinates I have selected in the image in my preferred format.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

There is a widgets module in matplotlib that can give you that functionality.  Check out the [widgets examples](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/widgets/index.html?highlight=widgets) page.